# .NET Framework 4.6.2 Installation failure on Windows Embedded Standard 7 SP1

Tags: windows, .net-4.6.2

I am working with a Industrial PC that is running Windows Embedded Standard and trying to install Zenon Software by Copa-Data.

The install process is getting stuck when it tries to install the .NET Framework 4.6.2. As per suggestion of Copa-Data I have tried installing the .NET Framework on its own and have gotten the same error.

[image: Extracting Files: Unspecified Error Encountered]

The log for the install reads the following:

```
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] === Logging started: 2018/03/16 10:40:45 ===
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Executable: C:\Users\JR\Desktop\NDP462-KB3151800-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe v4.6.1590.0
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] --- logging level: standard ---
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Successfully bound to the ClusApi.dll
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Error 0x80070424: Failed to open the current cluster
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Cluster drive map: ''
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Considering drive: 'C:\'...
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Considering drive: 'D:\'...
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Considering drive: 'E:\'...
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Considering drive: 'V:\'...
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Drive 'V:\' is rejected because of the unknown or unsuitable drive type
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Drive 'D:\' has been selected as the largest fixed drive
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Directory 'D:\60e4d655db57c07995\' has been selected for file extraction
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Extracting files to: D:\60e4d655db57c07995\
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract all files out of box container #0.
[3/16/2018, 10:40:45] Error 0x80004005: Failed to extract
[3/16/2018, 10:42:18] Exiting with result code: 0x80004005
[3/16/2018, 10:42:18] === Logging stopped: 2018/03/16 10:42:18 ===
```

I did find [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows-embedded/2015/08/10/microsoft-net-framework-versions-supported-by-windows-embedded-products/) page which makes me believe the Operating system is not the issue but am unsure of what else it can be. I have been running the install as administrator and I do have permissions to use drive D:\

Looking at it I do meet all of the other system requirements. Here are some other machine specs:[image: Computer Properties]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up switching to an Identical Machine and it worked. After that I did a system restore on this machine with the manufacturer provided USB and then all worked as it was supposed to.